# is there anyway to programatically get the data on a group's facebook wall through the API without having to popup a login screen

Tags: asp.net, facebook

i have a group page.  i am creating a website for the group and they want to be able to see the recent facebook updates (what you see on the group's facebook wall) on their website.

is this possible without having to have a facebook popup login and just programatically pass in my login information?

Comment: Hi, I also have this question, could you already provide some example code for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot programatically fill in login information, that is against the Facebook terms and conditions. You can, however, authenticate as an application as opposed to a user.
Use the following method:

```
Make a GET request to:
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET

Facebook returns:
access_token=SOME_TOKEN

Use this token as your access token and it should allow you to access the group. I have tested this with my application and can confirm it works.

You request the wall information via the request:
https://graph.facebook.com/GROUP_ID/feed?access_token=SOME_TOKEN
```

This will not pop up any login screens as you are not required to be logged in to view a public group. Ensure your privacy settings are public for the group as well.